# sql select statement with calculations

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select all trucks wityh a certain status and where created_at is past 24 hours

This is what i have tried

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_trucks WHERE `truck_status` != 11
```

Now am stuck on how to add the extra where statement such that i get only the trucks that are past 24 hours from current time. In literal terms this would be

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_trucks WHERE `truck_status` != 11
      ANDWHERE ('created_at'-NOW() <0 ) //created_at passes 24 hours
```

In usual php this would translate to

```
 $created_at= 1500373706; // created_At value in mysql db

if ((time() - $created_at) > 86400) { //past 24 hours mark
     //past 24 hours i need these
  } else {
     //not past 24 hours i dont need them
 }
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Using mysql database, added the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something like:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tbl_trucks t
WHERE t.truck_status <> 11 AND
      t.created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR);
```

Comment: am getting an error unrecognized keyword near interval

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following query to find all records whose status is not `11` and which were created in the last day:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tbl_trucks t
WHERE t.truck_status <> 11 AND
      t.created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```